# Find out if running INSIDE a @staticmethod of a class

Tags: python, class, static-methods

I use the following to figure if the function was called inside an object :

```
frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals
obj = frame['self'] if 'self' in frame else None
if obj is None : raise Exception("use only in objects")
```

Is there a way to figure out if I'm running INSIDE a @staticmethod of a class

Comment: What's the use case for this?

Comment: What if you call the static method from inside an instance method, or vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

`staticmethod` is a wrapper implementing [the descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors). The descriptor protocol applies during lookup of the method, it's not an extra layer in the stack frame (by the time the method is called, the descriptor is no longer involved). When you see `a.b()`, that's implemented as:

1. Load `a`
2. Load the `b` attribute of `a` (there are some quirky optimizations here in modern CPython, but the logical behavior remains the same)
3. Call the loaded `b`

`@staticmethod` inserts itself in step #2 (changing what you get from loading the `b` attribute), while only step #3 is visible in the stack trace.

You can apply various heuristics to *guess* at whether you're in a `staticmethod`, but nothing in the stack frame will directly tell you (an `@staticmethod` would look essentially identical to a plain function that's not part of any class; this isn't really wrong, since `@staticmethod` is basically a plain function using the class as a namespace, without actually using the class in any way). If you think you need to know this information, you're probably wrong, and you have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040) you're not telling us about.

Comment: i have a simple logger/debugger who check the obj attr it is executed under to either print or not.. i wanted to do similar checks inside staticmethod call : https://github.com/vsraptor/quick-debug/blob/master/debug.py

Comment: @sten: Yeah, that's largely nonsensical. Static methods *intentionally* discard all information about how they were invoked; the descriptor throws away the information about the instance (if any) and the class before calling it. Even what you're already doing is somewhat unreliable (assuming the `self` argument is actually named `self`, when it's only a convention). What you call "simple" is really "incredibly complex/hacky" already and the heuristics you'd have to add to do anything faintly useful with static methods would put what you've got to shame with its egregious terribleness.